# How to get value of a child of node-set?

Tags: xslt

I am using a variable in my XSLT to select correct node and then I want to use this variable to retrieve its child nodes:

```
<xsl:variable name="CorrectNode">
              <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="$Formula='14'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="f:node14" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$Formula='15'">
                     <xsl:value-of select="f:node15" />
                  </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<Revenue>
   <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($CorrectNode)/f1:revenueValue" />
</Revenue>
```

However, it does not output anything. If I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($CorrectNode)" />
```

or

```
<xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($CorrectNode)" />
```

then the values or nodes are outputted but how to access its children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet sets the variable to a result tree fragment consisting of one text node, whose value is the string value of the appropriate element.  The variable does *not* refer to the element itself, only its *string value*.

But you don't need the RTF and `node-set` function here at all, as you can do it with a straight `select` using appropriate predicates, since the `test` expressions are not context-dependent (a test like `$Formula = '15'` gives the same value regardless of whether the current context is the `f:node15` element or its parent):

```
<xsl:variable name="CorrectNode"
              select="f:node14[$Formula = '14'] | f:node15[$Formula = '15']" />
```

This way the variable is a reference to the original element, and you can navigate from there using XPath.